# How to convert Seq bool to UInt value in chisel?

Tags: chisel

I want to convert **Seq[Bool]** into a **UInt** value. I try **asUInt** method, but it report an error that **asUInt is not a member of IndexedSeq**.

For example:

```
val valid = Wire(Vec(4, Bool()))
val ready = Wire(Vec(4, Bool()))
val fire = (valid zip ready).map{case (vld, rdy) => vld && rdy}
val fire_mask = fire.asUInt()
```

Comment: You meant `val fire = (valid zip ready).map{` no ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should convert `fire` to Chisel `Vec` instead of Scala `Vector`:

```
val fire = VecInit((valid zip ready).map{case (vld, rdy) => vld && rdy})
```